# yaml-cpp doesn't compile with g++

Tags: yaml-cpp

I need to get yaml-cpp running, but it just won't compile without errors. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and yaml-cpp-0.5.1 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/), which was installed using 'cmake' and 'sudo make install' to make sure the libraries are correctly copied to the desired path '/usr/local/include/yaml-cpp'.

For testing purposes I tried to compile a few lines of code

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    YAML::Node config = YAML::Load("[1,2,3]");
    return 0;
}
```

which I basically got from this page [here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial). If I now run

```
g++ -o yaml_test yaml_test.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lyaml-cpp -o yaml_test yaml_test.cpp
```

I get always the same error message

```
/tmp/ccgvKdN2.o: In function `main':
yaml_test.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `YAML::Load(char const*)'
```

which as far as I know means that the libraries have not been found.

What is going on here? Why won't it just compile?

Comment: Can you verify that `libyaml-cpp.a` is in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Yes this is in fact the case.

Comment: Can you try copying `libyaml-cpp.a` to the same directory as `yaml_test.cpp` and recompiling?

Comment: One more thing: can you check if your package comes with a different version of yaml-cpp installed? E.g., look in `/usr/lib`, and also look in `/usr/local/lib` for `libyaml-cpp.*` to see if an old dynamic library was already there.

Comment: Ok I copied this file, but it didn't change the error message. I found the files `libyaml-cpp.so`, `libyaml-cpp.so.0.2` and `libyaml-cpp.so.0.2.7` in `/usr/lib` and `libyaml-cpp.a` in `/usr/local/lib`. I guess this means that the package manager installed version 0.2.7 and I manually installes 0.5.1, which may have resulted in a confusion somehow. I already tried `sudo aptitude remove yaml-cpp`, which was quite a bad idea, since it removed a lot of other stuff that I am still using as well. So I had to reinstall everything again. Is there some other way to just remove this one package?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it looks like yaml-cpp 0.2.7 is already installed in your system. You have two options:

1. Remove the existing package from your system. I'm not sure exactly how `aptitude` works, but you can try simply deleting the files `/usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.*` and `/usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/` and then installing yaml-cpp 0.5.1 from scratch. (Note that you probably had a conflict with header files too, but got lucky that it was resolved properly. I'd delete the 0.2.7 headers and then install 0.5.1 fresh.)
2. You can install 0.5.1 into a separate location (e.g., `$HOME/lib` and `$HOME/include`), and then make sure that those directories are checked before `/usr/local` in your path variables.

I'd probably choose option #1, since I'm not sure why you'd need both installed. I suppose it's possible some other packages that your package manager wants to install will depend on yaml-cpp 0.2.7, which could be a problem.

Comment: Ok, I now removed all yaml-cpp stuff that I found in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` and reinstalled yaml-cpp 0.5.1. Unfortunately for some reason I still get the very same error as before, hence the version 0.2.7 install could not have been the problem after all...

Comment: Is there any stuff elsewhere? `/opt`? If you're actually linking to the `libyaml-cpp.a` that's built from 0.5.1, then you won't get this error, so there must be something else that's being linked. Maybe try option #2?

Comment: I tried option #2 as well, unfortunately it made no improvement. Just to make sure that I get it correctly: `-I/usr/local/include` seems to work fine, but `-L/usr/local/lib -lyaml-cpp` which should link the file `/usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a` does not work. But the file `libyaml-cpp.a` itself has been found, because otherwise the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lyaml-cpp` would appear instead of `yaml_test.cpp:(.text+....): undefined reference to ...`.

Comment: So altogether this means that all the files have been loaded correctly but still all the YAML functions have not been found.

Comment: No - presumably it's finding *some* library for `yaml-cpp`, but not the version you compiled from 0.5.1 (otherwise it would find the reference!). I think you might be able to explicitly pass a `.a` file to `gcc`; instead of passing `-L... -lyaml-cpp`, try just appending `/usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a` to the command line args.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I'm using `g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -o yaml_test yaml-test.cpp /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a` which compiles just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

check all required libs are linked properly with **ldd** command.

ldd ./yaml_test

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff631bc000)
    **libyaml-cpp.so.0.6 => not found**
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6e99a93000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6e99791000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6e9957b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6e991b7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005614b86c1000)
```

if any lib link is missed, export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to .so>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH